# How to create GD Image from base64 encoded jpeg?

Tags: php, image, gd, base64, jpeg

I have an upload Api that as a response object delivers (along with other stuff inside a Json object) a base64 encoded jpeg image.

I create the encoded image as so:

```
$im; // gd image resource
ob_start();
imagejpeg($im);
$data = base64_encode(ob_get_clean());
```

The data then is put inside a form field using javascript and submitted.

How can I create a GD resource from that again so that I actually can save that image as a file?

Everything in PHP.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use [imagecreatefromstring()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php) function:

```
$data = base64_decode($_POST['image_as_base64']);

$formImage = imagecreatefromstring($data);
```

"String" does not mean a "real" string. In that case it means bytes/blob data.

Answer (score 13):

> How can I create a GD resource from that again so that I actually can save that image as a file?

Are you sure you need to do that extra step? How about:

```
file_put_contents('MyFile.jpg', base64_decode($_POST['MyFormField']));
```

Comment: yeah, looks the best way ;) my mind was somehow blocked :D +1 but gonna accept the other answer because it was a directa answer to my q

Comment: @Joe Hopfgartner - Harrumph! Well, a Happy New Year to you anyway, whenever that is for you. :D

Comment: sometimes this step doesn't cut it.  TCPDF some software I use chocked on this but worked with GD

Answer (score 0):

I did by this way:

```
// input is in format: data:image/png;base64,...
$str="data:image/png;base64,"; 
$data=str_replace($str,"",$_POST['image']); 
$data = base64_decode($data);
file_put_contents('tmp/'.mktime().'.png', $data);
```