# How to create and save image to a website folder from a base64 encoded data/string using PHP

Tags: php, image, base64

I have the following code on my php file which is working fine, Its decoding a base64 string and showing that as a image on the webpage, but i want it to save it on a folder too.

```
<?php
$base = $_POST['encoded'];
$base = base64_decode($base);

$im = imagecreatefromstring($base);
if ($im !== false) {
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
}
else {
    echo 'An error occurred.';
}
?>
```

i have already tried the solution described on these links but none of these are worked for me

[How to save a PNG image server-side, from a base64 data string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511511/how-to-save-a-png-image-server-side-from-a-base64-data-string)

[How to create GD Image from base64 encoded jpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572121/how-to-create-gd-image-from-base64-encoded-jpeg)

what will be the extra line of code which could save this image to a folder

Comment: `imagepng();` has a second parameter which is file name/file path.

Comment: already tested with imagepng($im,'image.png'); its stop displaying image on webspage and not even save it on the folder

Comment: It would stop displaying, true but it should output to the same directory as the executing file. Is the file not in the same space as the page running this script?

Comment: yeah the file is in the same place. but not saving the image on same directory

Comment: oh now i got it. its the file permission issue. writing permission was off thats why its not creating the image. now imagepng($im,'image.png'); is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file permissions was not set to writing mode. set it to 777 and tested with the following code.

```
<?php
$base = $_POST['encoded'];
$base = base64_decode($base);

$im = imagecreatefromstring($base);
if ($im !== false) {
    header('Content-Type: image/png');

    imagepng($im,'image.png'); // saving image to the same directory

    imagedestroy($im);

}
else {
    echo 'An error occurred.';
}
?>
```

Comment: If you create a function, you can make two images, one that saves to file, one that displays

Answer (score 0):

```
$base = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABwAAAASCAMAAAB/2U7WAAAABl'
       .'BMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAASUlEQVR4XqWQUQoAIAxC2/0vXZDr'
       .'EX4IJTRkb7lobNUStXsB0jIXIAMSsQnWlsV+wULF4Avk9fLq2r'
       .'8a5HSE35Q3eO2XP1A1wQkZSgETvDtKdQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';
$base = base64_decode($base);

$im = imagecreatefromstring($base);
if ($im !== false) {
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
}
else {
    echo 'An error occurred.';
}
```

Well the code worked for me.
If you see a blank page, that means the string encoded was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for JPEG image

```
$data = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD2wBDAAYEBQYFBAYGBQYHBwYIChAKCgkJChQODwwQFxQYGBcUFhYaHSUfGhsjHB'; // image data 

define('UPLOAD_DIR','dir_path/'); // image dir path

list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data); 

list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);

$data = str_replace(' ', '+', $data);

$data = base64_decode($data); // base 64 decoding 

file_put_contents(UPLOAD_DIR.$img_name.".jpeg", $data); // saving the image to required path
```