# Save cropped image to local server and it URL to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, image

I am using [cropit](https://github.com/scottcheng/cropit) to crop image.

```
  <body>
    <div class="image-editor">
      <input type="file" class="cropit-image-input">
      <!-- .cropit-image-preview-container is needed for background image to work -->
      <div class="cropit-image-preview-container">
        <div class="cropit-image-preview"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="image-size-label">
        Resize image
      </div>
      <input type="range" class="cropit-image-zoom-input">
      <button class="export">Save</button>
    </div>

    <script>
      $(function() {
        $('.image-editor').cropit({
          exportZoom: 1.25,
          imageBackground: true,
          imageBackgroundBorderWidth: 10,
          imageState: {
            src: '../image/default-avatar.png'
          }
        });

        $('.export').click(function() {
          var imageData = $('.image-editor').cropit('export');
          window.open(imageData);

        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
```

I have faced two issues:

1. When i do the cropping and clicking on save button cropped image opens in new window. I want that it should not open in new window, instead cropped image should save to related user folder like:
   `ROOT_PATH.'user/upload/'.$row['UserName'].'/avatar/big/'`
2. I want to also save the latest cropped image URL to be saved in MySQL database in `AvatarImage` column.

**Beneath find MySQL database information:**

Database name: ara

Database user: root

Database password:

Database address: 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

you must encode base64 image file using php, and save your image to a file directory,
please try to trick existing like this link

[How to create and save image to a website folder from a base64 encoded data/string using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27416874/how-to-create-and-save-image-to-a-website-folder-from-a-base64-encoded-data-stri)